# Combine matrices - numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have four numpy matrix, each which shape is `(2544, 2544).` I wish to combine them to create a matrix which is `(2544, 2544)` by adding the corresponding elements from each. How can I do this? For example if I had this matrix:

```
x = [1,2
     3,4]
y = [4,3
     2,2]
```

my desired output would be:

```
d = [5,5
    5,6]
```

Comment: Is this how you are defining your matrices?  Because these would be 1-D lists.  You'd want to define them like `x = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])`.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to reflect your question edits.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my answer to reflect your specific question, but if you define your variables as matrices, you can simply add the variables as long as they are the same shape.  Some example code is seen below:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
y = np.matrix([[4,3],[2,2]])

d = x + y
print d
```

which returns:

```
[[5 5]
 [5 6]]
```

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: You can use the np.array function on your matrix variables, or they may have an asarray method. On my phone right now posting but can provide more help later if needed.

Comment: @user7347576 I've edited my answer.  It seems that matrices can be added explicitly, but for other mathematical operations, you can convert to an array like I've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your matrix are identified as a tuple `matrices = (A,B,C,D)`.

Just aggregate them `ABCD=np.dstack(matrices)`. then sum the result : `ABCD.sum(axis=2)`.